# import.io and portia regex url patterns

Tags: regex, import.io, portia

I am using data scrapers: Import.io & Portia.

They both allow you to define a regular expression for the crawler to abide by.
for example the url: https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/pdi-medical

how would I account for the ending "pdi-medical"?

I've looked all over and understand how to use regex in a JS environment, but I'm a little confused as to what I'd exactly put in the input on Portia/Import.io

Something like this?
https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries//^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$/

Answer (score 0):

For Portia, if you want your crawler to follow any URLs starting with https://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/, you can just add a crawling rule with the following regex:

`^https?://weedmaps.com/dispensaries/`

Comment: Thank you! I ran that and I'm only getting dispensaries in California, not any other states. any idea why this might be?

Comment: Are the URLs for other states available in your start pages? And do they have the same URL pattern?